# Set focus to an Input in a gwtbootstrap3 Modal

Tags: gwt, twitter-bootstrap-3, gwtbootstrap3

I want to set the focus to a certain field (`org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.Input`) in a dialog (`org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.Modal`) before the dialog shows up. The use case seem quite common, if you have a dialog with a single field like the *Upload text* or *Add feed* dialogs [right here](http://www.speedapp.io/webapp.jsp#Read). However I could not figure out how to set the focus to this particular [gwtbootstrap3](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3) component.

The `Input` component does have a `setFocus(true)` method. I assumed that setting the focus before showing the dialog would not work, which it doesn't. So the logical solution is to put the method call inside a `ScheduledCommand`. Like this:

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        textField.setFocus(true);
    }

});
```

That usually works with GWT standard components, but does not seem to help in this case. I found a way to get notified once the dialog is shown through a `ModalShowHandler`. Like this:

```
modal.addShowHandler(new ModalShowHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onShow(ModalShowEvent evt) {
        textField.setFocus(true);
    }

});
```

I even tried to combine both, adding a deferred call to the handle. No luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be listening on the `ModalShownEvent` (note: `Shown`, not `Show`).

`ModalShowEvent` is fired when the modal is *requested* (for example, programmatically) to be shown.

`ModalShownEvent` is fired when the modal is actually shown.

This somewhat confusing naming is based on the events of the native [Bootstrap Modal's events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events): `show.bs.modal` and `shown.bs.modal`.

`ModalShownEvent` combined with the usual `Scheduler#scheduleDeferred` should do the trick.

Comment: Works like a charm. Even without a deferred call.